# click on list items using java script executor in selenium web driver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I have a requirement to collect multiple links and click on each link to extract some information from the website to the excel.So i have collected all links in one list and i am trying to click on each element depending on the index. I am not getting any exception and the click is also not performing on the element.I struck in clicking on link using javascript executor.Normal click and actions are not working here.

```
List<WebElement> titles=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='product-name']"));
for(int i=0;i<titles.size();i++)
    {
    String title1=titles.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println(title1);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
        if(titles.get(i).isEnabled())
        {
        System.out.println("TAKE ACTION");
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", titles.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you share the HTML snippet?

Comment: <h2 class="product-name">

Comment: I am giving the sample snippet  <h2 class="product-name"><a href=" https: it is in .html" title="some title" class="product image"><imgsrc="  "></a> <div class="product shop"><h2 class="product-name"><a href=" https: it is in .html" title="some title" class="product image"><imgsrc="  "></a> </h2>..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your HTML you could collect all the `href` url instead of clicking in the header.

Sample code:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//h2[@class='product-name']//a"));
for (WebElement element : elements) {
    driver.navigate().to(element.getAttribute("href"));
}
```

Comment: Thank u ..but after clicking on one link it is throwing stale element exception

Comment: Did you click on the anchor link after using navigate? You don't need to click on the link. Once you navigate to href url the new page will open(similar to if you click on the link).

Comment: If you think the answer is helpful please upvote and mark the answer as accepted. Thank you